# Dissappearing arrow and styling on <select> element in Safari on iOS

Tags: ios, css, ipad, safari

I am finding when I style  elements (specifically, with `background: transparent`), the arrow is missing in Safari on iOS. Have any of you experienced this or know why it's hiding the browser chrome? Can I use conditional statements to apply CSS just for Safari on iOS (without JS)?

The device is running iOS 6.1.2.

here is a screenshot on Safari in iOS (iPad2):

[image: Safari iOS]

Here is a screenshot on Safari (desktop, Windows 7, same for all other desktop browsers):

[image: Safari Desktop]

CSS:

```
select.choose_state,
select.choose_state option {
    background: transparent;
}
select.choose_state {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    outline: none;

    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 35px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

HTML:

`<select name="state_select" id="state_select" class="choose_state" size="1">[...]</select>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you tell webkit to remove all default styling, it will remove it, also the arrow (in iOS). You will have to create a arrow and shift it over the select field.

I made [this pen](http://codepen.io/loredonut/pen/xvtHG), include everything with `.dblarrow` (CSS and HTML) and add styles marked with `/*Important*/`.

Comment: Thanks! I had to apply some conditional formatting so the extra arrows are visible only in Safari, but this worked.

Answer (score 2):

A very late answer but a little trick for people.

The code below keep the select transparent on desktop but let the default select style on iOS.

```
select {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.005);
}
```

Comment: weird & incorrect! it is surely a problem with your screen, If I do this in my device, I will see a light dark background like a shadow ! it is not 100% transparent