# How to remove gloss effect on safari mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I noticed the color of select controls are wrong with safari for mobiles.

There's a gloss like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638677/how-can-i-remove-the-gloss-on-a-select-element-in-safari-on-mac) mentioned.

Unfortunately, the solution removes also the little arrow at the right.

Is there an other way than `-webkit-appearance:none;` to override only the color.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `-webkit-appearance:caret;`? ( http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2010/04/22/disable_the_default_inner_shadow_of_search_inputs_on_the_ipad )

Comment: Already tried and no luck :(

Comment: You could try this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623389/dissappearing-arrow-and-styling-on-select-element-in-safari-on-ios Seems that can't remove styling while keeping arrow so you gotta make one by yourself.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this solution. Can you write this as an answer so I can accept it if there's no other way. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposedly, `-webkit-appearance:caret;` should've remove the gloss. But seems does not work in selects.

Therefore, the only way I could find was the same of the [Florija's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15624210/684932), which is faking the select arrow via CSS.

HTML:

```
<select name="state_select" id="state_select" class="choose_state" size="1">
    <option>Hey</option>
</select>
<div class="dblarrow"><b></b><i></i></div>
```

CSS:

```
.dblarrow {
    margin-left: -35px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dblarrow b {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.dblarrow i {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    display: block;
}

select.choose_state,
select.choose_state option {
    background: transparent;
}
select.choose_state {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    outline: none;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding-right: 20px; /*Important*/
    display: inline-block; /*Important*/
}
```

Check out his pen: http://codepen.io/loredonut/pen/xvtHG