# How to remove gloss effect on safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16593308/4295879) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593308/how-to-remove-gloss-effect-on-safari-mobile), My problem still hasn't been solved.
The solution removed everything including the values, arrows and borders.

My code goes like this.

```css
.form-control {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 28px;
 padding: 6px 12px;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 12;
 color: #666;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin-top:5px;
 -webkit-appearance:caret;
 }
```

```html
<select class="form-control" value="number">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you specify your problem please?

Comment: Explain the issue in your question so that we don't have to follow a trail to see what you are on about

Answer (score 0):

if you intend to re-style the select input, you can implement -webkit-appearance: none, and add your own style:

```css
.custom-select{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 0;
  
  /* Add your own arrow image and set it as a background image */
}
```

```html
<select class="custom-select" value="number">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
</select>
```

The method above will work on -webkit based browser like chrome, safari. But in firefox there still a bug, it's still showing the ugly arrow.